# few issues with dirPagination: angular is not defined exception plus ng-class and ng-show not working

Tags: angularjs, bower, ng-class, ng-show, dirpagination

I am very satisfied with dirPagination since it helped me considerably to make the pagination functionality in my angulaJs 1.3.8 application. Nevertheless, I am stuck in a very simple issue: I couldn't make the sort icon appears and the arrows (<< < > >>) didn't look similar to the layout of my page. Additionally, I am seeing certain error in Chrome which doesn't seem to negatively impact the application "UnCaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined dirPagination.js.28 (anonymous function).

Interesting is that all functionalities are working: (1) if I click in > it will go to next page and (2) if I click on to of the header table it will sort accordingly to the column and (3) if I type a text in search it will anrrow the table consequently. The problem is really a matter of stetic and the "UnCaught ReferenceError" (maybe both have a single root cause).

I added below all code relevant to my question. I guess either I am using certain css impacting dirPagination or I didn't added it correctly. I used bower install angular-utils-pagination.

If desire, almost the entire application can be found in https://github.com/jhades/spring-mvc-angularjs-sample-app (all credits for jhades author) except the changes showed below.

The changes showed below are more or less based on http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/06/01/search-sort-and-pagination-ngrepeat-angularjs/

P.S. please don't compare dirPagination with others alternatives. I tried uibpagination and I couldn't manage it certainly because I missed certain knowledge - you can check here if you get interested [why I am getting “Template for directive 'uibPagination' must have exactly one root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361311/why-i-am-getting-template-for-directive-uibpagination-must-have-exactly-one-r).

calories-counter-app.js

```
angular.module('caloriesCounterApp', ['editableTableWidgets', 'frontendServices', 'spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])

       .filter('excludeDeleted', function () {

           return function (input) {

               return _.filter(input, function (item) {

                   return item.deleted == undefined || !item.deleted;

               });

           }

       })

    .controller('CaloriesTrackerCtrl', ['$scope' , 'MealService', 'UserService', 'LifeCycleService', '$timeout',

        function ($scope, MealService, UserService, IcaService, LifeCycleService, $timeout) {

…



            $scope.sort = function(keyname){

                $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed

                $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa

            }



….
```

calories-tracker.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="/resources/bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

<title>ICTT - FLEXIBLE LIFECYCLE</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/bower_components/pure/pure.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"

       href="/resources/bower_components/pure/grids-responsive.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/public/css/pure-theme.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/public/css/calories-tracker.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">



</head>

<body class="pure-skin-theme" id="caloriesCounterApp"

       ng-controller="CaloriesTrackerCtrl">





….



                     <div class="form-group">

                   <label >Search</label>

                   <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">

               </div>



                     <table class="pure-table">

                           <thead>

                                  <tr>

                                         <th class="selection-column"></th>

                                         <th ng-click="sort('ica')">Customers

                                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='ica'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>

                                         </th>

                                         <th ng-click="sort('version')">Acceptance Brand</th>

                                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='version'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>

                                         <th ng-click="sort('incomingMessages')">Occurrence</th>

                                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='incomingMessages'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>

                                  </tr>

                           </thead>



                           <tbody>

                                  <tr  dir-paginate="lifeCycle in vm.lifeCycles|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">



                                         <td class="selection-column"><input type="checkbox"

                                                ng-model="lifeCycle.selected" ng-click="selectionChanged()"></td>



                                         <td value="lifeCycle.ica.ica" is-new="lifeCycle.new">

                                                {{lifeCycle.ica.ica}}



                                         </td>



                                         <td value="lifeCycle.version" is-new="lifeCycle.new">

                                                {{lifeCycle.version}}

                                         </td>



                                         <td value="lifeCycle.incomingMessages" is-new="lifeCycle.new">



                                                {{lifeCycle.incomingMessages}}

                                         </td>



                                  </tr>



                           </tbody>

                     </table>

                     <dir-pagination-controls max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" tamplate-url="dirPagination.tpl.html"> </dir-pagination-controls>



…





       <script type="text/javascript"

              data-main="/resources/js/run-calories-tracker"

              src="/resources/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>







</body>
```

Used by requiresjs pattern run-calories-tracker.js (this is probably not relevant to my question but I showed here in case I am wrong)

```
require.config({

    paths: {

        angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular',

        angularMessages: '../bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages',

        csrfInterceptor: '../bower_components/spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor/dist/spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor.min',

        lodash: "../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash",

        jQuery: "./datetimepicker/jquery", // needed only by the date time picker

        datetimepicker: './datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker',

        editableTableWidgets: '../public/js/editable-table-widgets',

        frontendServices: 'frontend-services',

        dirPagination: '../bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination',

        caloriesCounterApp: "calories-counter-app"

    },

    shim: {

        jQuery: {

            exports: "jQuery"

        },

        angular: {

            exports: "angular"

        },

        dirPagination: {

              deps: ['angular']

        },

        csrfInterceptor: {

            deps: ['angular']

        },

        datetimepicker: {

            deps: ['jQuery']

        },

        angularMessages: {

            deps: ['angular']

        },

        editableTableWidgets: {

            deps: ['angular', 'lodash', 'datetimepicker', 'jQuery']

        },

        frontendServices: {

            deps: ['angular', 'lodash', 'csrfInterceptor']

        },

        caloriesCounterApp: {

            deps: [ 'lodash', 'angular', 'angularMessages', 'editableTableWidgets' , 'frontendServices', 'dirPagination']

        }

    }

});



require(['caloriesCounterApp'], function () {



    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('caloriesCounterApp'), ['caloriesCounterApp']);



});
```

[image: chrome]

***Edited in 2016/Jully/14 Brazilia time

[image: eclipse]

Comment: `<dir-pagination-controls max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" tamplate-url="dirPagination.tpl.html"> </dir-pagination-controls>` Make sure it's the correct path. Maybe it's `'../bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination/dirPagination.tpl.html'`, no?

Comment: @developer033, certainly the path isn't angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination/... Kindly, see the picture just added. Nevertheless, it can be a problem with some include but I don't know what and where to check.

Comment: Please, note in my question that I have not added dirPagination.tpl.html beyond <dir-pagination-controls> tag. On another hand, dirPagination.js was added in three places: 1. on top of my html with <script>, 2. it was declared in require.config and 3. it was included in angular.module in my angularjs control. Should I added dirPagination.tpl.html in other place other than the dir-pagination-controls?